# Find date range with most occurrences

Tags: c#, mysql, algorithm

I have a MySql table that looks like this:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   DateTime
14         10         15      2015-01-01 21:45:00
0          0          0       2015-01-01 21:46:00
12         8          16      2015-01-015 21:46:30
13         7          15      2015-01-01 21:47:00
0          0          0       2015-01-01 21:48:10
.          .          .       .
.          .          .       .
.          .          .       .
// Many non-zero rows here
.          .          .       .

14         10         15      2015-01-02 20:04:00
0          0          0       2015-01-02 20:04:30
12         8          16      2015-01-02 20:04:40
0          0          0       2015-01-02 20:04:50
10         5          2       2015-01-02 20:04:55
0          0          0       2015-01-02 20:05:00
11         4          8       2015-01-02 20:05:05
0          0          0       2015-01-02 20:05:10
12         15         16      2015-01-02 20:05:30
.          .          .       .
.          .          .       .
.          .          .       .
// Many other rows here where zeros doesn't happen so often.
```

This represents the quality of an user's internet connection in a given moment. A all-zero row means the connection dropped (note that there is no way only one column will have a zero value in a given row - either they're all zero, or all non-zero). This then means, from this example data, this user's worst period was from `2015-01-02 20:04:30` to `2015-01-02 20:05:30`, because the connection dropped four times in one minute. How can I find this period of time in C# (or mysql, if it is not too cumbersome)?

And by the way, is there a specific name for this? I haven't had much luck googling a solution for it because most of the questions I find are about trying to find the longest streak (only consecutive occurrences, not the most close ones, like I need to find), or something like that.

---

Update: I was going to talk to one of my CS teachers today, but I was unable to. I'll talk to him tomorrow instead. Meanwhile, some friends and I have been thinking on how to solve this, and we've come to something which we're not sure if it's a correct solution (as you can see, we're not really good with math/statistics). We've thought about doing this:

For each all-zero column in the table, we compare it with the last one and all others before it. Like this:

```
Compare first all-zero row with last one; 
Compare first all-zero row with second last one;
 ... 
Compare first all-zero row with the second one. 
Do it all over again starting on the second all-zero row this time.
```

Then we get the worst time intervals for this user's connection, being the worst one that in which `(Number of times the connection dropped in time interval T) divided by T` has the greater value. But, as I said before, we don't even know if this would land us the right answer. Also, this seems to be pretty computationally expensive and right now we have a database with a couple thousands of rows.

Comment: It's not too cumbersome in MySQL, but you need to start with properly formatted dates.

Comment: What do you mean? Note that I'm using the MySQL `datetime` type for the date column (and the data comes from a DateTime object in c#).

Comment: Ok, for some reason they're not appearing as Y-m-d above

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, that's because I'm from Brazil and we use d-m-y here. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, had a bit more time to think about this.  It's fairly easy to think of this problem in object-oriented pseudocode, because it basically boils down to finding a max value in an array:

```
int timeInterval = 30 (or however many seconds you want)
Sort all rows in ascending date/time order
Row worstStartRow = rows[0]
int worstNumBadConnections = 0
For each row X
    If X is defined as a dropped connection
        int tempNumBadConnections = 0
        For every subsequent row Y
            If (Y.time - X.time) > timeInterval
                break
            Else if Y is defined as a dropped connection
                tempNumBadConnections++
        If tempNumBadConnections > worstNumBadConnections
            worstNumBadConnections = tempNumBadConnections
            worstStartRow = X
// worst time interval starts at worstStartRow.time,
// ends at worstStartRow.time + timeInterval
```

But of course SQL doesn't do row-wise processing very well.  To get around this, we can join the table to itself, ensure that the times of the paired rows from our two "tables" fall within a certain range, and aggregate the output.

Say we have a table `Demo` that looks like this:

```
Id  Zero  Time
0   0     '2007-12-31 11:11:11'
1   0     '2008-01-01 00:00:00'
2   0     '2008-01-01 00:00:30'
3   1     '2008-01-01 00:00:30'
4   0     '2008-01-01 00:00:31'
5   1     '2008-01-01 00:00:31'
6   0     '2008-01-01 00:00:32'
7   0     '2008-01-01 11:11:11'
```

For each row with row.Zero = 0, we want to find all rows where Zero = 0 AND the time of the other row is no more than N seconds later than the time of the first row.  So, if your interval is 30 seconds long, the query might look like this:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Time, b.Id, b.Time
FROM Demo a
INNER JOIN Demo b
  ON a.Zero = b.Zero
  AND a.Time <= b.Time
WHERE a.Zero = 0
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.Time, b.Time) <= 30
ORDER BY a.Id, b.Time
;
```

This gives us a series of rows containing 1) the Id of the zero row that defines the start of an interval, 2) the time of that starting row, 3) the Id of another row in that interval, and 4) the time of that other row:

```
Id  Time                            Id  Time
0   'December, 31 2007 11:11:11'    0   'December, 31 2007 11:11:11'
1   'January, 01 2008 00:00:00'     1   'January, 01 2008 00:00:00'
1   'January, 01 2008 00:00:00'     2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'
2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'     2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'
2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'     4   'January, 01 2008 00:00:31'
2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'     6   'January, 01 2008 00:00:32'
4   'January, 01 2008 00:00:31'     4   'January, 01 2008 00:00:31'
4   'January, 01 2008 00:00:31'     6   'January, 01 2008 00:00:32'
6   'January, 01 2008 00:00:32'     6   'January, 01 2008 00:00:32'
7   'January, 01 2008 11:11:11'     7   'January, 01 2008 11:11:11'
```

We can see that non-zero rows are excluded entirely, and rows are only matched to a starting row if their time is between 0 and 30 seconds later (inclusive) than the first row.  So far, so good!  But we'd also like to count these results by the Id of the starting row.  So we'll make the query aggregate the results, like so:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Time, COUNT(b.Id) numDropped
FROM Demo a
INNER JOIN Demo b
  ON a.Time <= b.Time
  AND a.Zero = b.Zero
WHERE a.Zero = 0
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.Time, b.Time) <= 30
GROUP BY a.Id
;
```

Which gives us rows containing 1) the Id of the zero row that defines the start of an interval, 2) the time of that starting row, and 3) the number of zero rows in the interval, including the starting row:

```
Id  Time                            numDropped
0   'December, 31 2007 11:11:11'    1
1   'January, 01 2008 00:00:00'     2
2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'     3
4   'January, 01 2008 00:00:31'     2
6   'January, 01 2008 00:00:32'     1
7   'January, 01 2008 11:11:11'     1
```

And to get only the "worst", we can simply take the previous query, order by `numDropped` in descending order, and get the first row:

```
ORDER BY numDropped DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

Which gives us:

```
Id  Time                            numDropped
2   'January, 01 2008 00:00:30'     3
```

You now have the start time of your worst interval, along with the Id of the first connection attempt and the number of dropped connections in that interval!  If you want the end time of the worst interval to come back in your query as well (rather than calculating it in the consuming program), you could additionally `SELECT` on `a.Time + INTERVAL 30 SECOND`.  Again, swap out 30 for however many seconds long your interval should be.

A couple of quick side notes:

1) You'll notice that zero rows join on themselves, which doesn't quite fit the earlier notion of processing *subsequent* rows.  But we need this - because what if the worst interval only had one dropped connection?  So each zero row needs to be able to include itself in its list of nearby zero rows.

2) Joining on `a.Time <= b.Time` avoids creating duplicate joined rows that we know we don't want anyway, so the query doesn't have to waste time processing them later.  You can, however, remove that clause and replace the timestamp check with a more explicit `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.Time, b.Time) BETWEEN 0 AND 30`, and you will get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the calendar half minute with the worst connections, then it is easy, an aggregation query.  Something like this:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (30))) as periodstart,
       count(*) as numrows,
       sum(column1 = 0 and column2 = 0 and column3 = 0) as numallzeros
from table t
group by floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (30))
order by numallzeros desc;
```

If you want to flexibly define the period, then that is much harder.  If so, you need to explain in the question how that should be done.

Comment: So, if I understand your answer right, this method will show the worst period by searching for a preset period of time, like: this user's worst minute; or this user's worst day; this user's worst 45min. Is that right?

Comment: @andre_ss6 More precisely, this answer divides time into 30-second chunks (12:00:01 to 12:00:30, 12:00:31 to 12:01:00, etc.), then finds the chunk with the most dropped connections.  And that's fine as long as you're okay with using chunks with predefined start and end times.  If, however, you want to find the worst 30 seconds, *regardless of when those 30 seconds actually fell on the clock* - say, a worst interval that happened between 01:02:11 and 01:02:41 - that's a lot harder to do in pure SQL.

Comment: I see. Still, even the hardest way you mention uses predefined time intervals. I'm trying to get to a solution which doesn't use one. I mean, the algorithm would analyze all the data and come up with the worst interval (that in which the result of the division `(number of dropped connections)/(time interval)` had the higher value) independently of how long was that interval. In all sincerity I have completely no idea how to do this. I've tried (and I'm still trying) to get something, but it obviously isn't easy. I'm going to talk to some mathematicians tomorrow to see if I get any help. :)

Comment: Also, note that we only need to consider one column, not 3